# (Swift) UITextView not displaying text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

I'm making a text-based iOS game which uses a single view consisting of a UITextView (scrollable, not editable) and a UITextField. I've made it so when I press return while editing the textField, the keyboard closes and the text of the textField is added to the textView. However, the text of the UITextView doesn't appear at all. The background color still appears, but nothing else, no matter how I try to display it. I've already tried setting the font size and color.

Here's code from the ViewController that handles both UI components.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    // outlets / actions
    @IBOutlet weak var outputView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
    var uni: Universe? // a custom class that contains the game's data

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //outputView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
        inputField.delegate = self
        outputView.delegate = self
        inputField.text = "press return for help"
        outputView.text = ""
        outputView.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        outputView.frame = self.view.frame
        // The next 3 lines make a new Universe object.
        uni = Assembler.build(outputView)
        uni!.setUni()
        uni!.setParser()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        uni!.player.viewLocation()
    }

    // delegate method; this should do 3 things:
    // 1. remove the keyboard
    // 2. call uni.parser.read(text)
    // 3. remove the text in the field

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        outputView.text! += textField.text! + "\n"
        uni!.parser!.read(textField.text!) // This function interprets the text from textField and prints something appropriate in the textView.
        textField.text = ""
        return true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // The rest of the code makes the whole frame shift up/down when the keyboard appears/disappears to keep the UITextField visible.
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. The similar questions on this site haven't given me anything to go on.

Comment: what is `uni!.parser!.read(textField.text!)` doing? Does the text in textview show if you comment this line out?

Comment: `uni!.parser!.read(textField.text!)` is supposed to add more text to the textview. Commenting it out didn't change anything.

Comment: Does the keyboard disappear on tapping return on keyboard? This will confirm if the `textFieldShouldReturn` is firing at all.

Comment: What if you force the code to run on the main thread? Try putting the code that updates the text inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //Reload Data Here
        })

Comment: Kashif: The keyboard does disappear, the text field behaves as it should. So we know `textFieldShouldReturn` is being executed.

Comment: Rocket101: I might have misunderstood you, but I put these two lines: `outputView.text! += textField.text! + "\n"` and `uni!.parser!.read(textField.text!)` inside dispatch_async within `textFieldShouldReturn` and nothing changed. Was that what you were suggesting?

Comment: Are you able to put a string into the UITextView if you do it in the viewDidLoad? Or will it never respond? Are you sure the IBOutlet is connected?

Comment: Nothing I add to `outputView.text!` appears, including the default text I set in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Does this work for you:- `outputView.text! += inputField.text! + "\n"`